# Flush left and right tabular environments in same line

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am writing a declaration for my thesis. I want the signature and place, date parts to be on the extreme left and right respectively. I used `\flushleft` and `\flushright`, but the result is not as expected.

I am using tabular as I have to use `\includegraphics` to include my signature.

```
\leavevmode
\vfill\noindent
\begin{center}
    \textbf{DECLARATION}
\end{center}
„I hereby ensure the sole composure of the Master thesis without any other sources
than the ones mentioned or any other auxiliary means. All parts taken from other sources in verbatim or gist manner are indicated appropriately“.

\vspace*{4em}\noindent
\hfill
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \vspace{-5.5mm}\includegraphics{Figures/Signature}\\
    \rule{10em}{0.4pt}\\ Signature
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\hfill
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \vspace{-5.5mm}Stade, 19.10.2021\\
    \rule{10em}{0.4pt}\\ Place, Date
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\hfill\strut
```

[image]

Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd avoid cluttering the document with so many commands.

Having a definition for `\declaratory` is better because you have a “centralized” place where to make the final typographic decisions.

The command has

- a first optional argument for the options to `\includegraphics`;
- a mandatory argument for the file name of the signature;
- the place and date.

The interface makes it easier to insert for instance a `trim` option in the appropriate spot for lowering the signature or removing white space around it.

The two parts below are aligned thanks to `tabular*`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\declaratory}[3][]{%
  \clearpage % or \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
  \begin{center}
  \bfseries DECLARATION
  \end{center}

  \vspace{4ex}

  \noindent
  I hereby ensure the sole composure of the Master thesis
  without any other sources than the ones mentioned or any
  other auxiliary means. All parts taken from other sources
  in verbatim or gist manner are indicated appropriately.

  \vspace{8ex}

  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{}c@{}}
  \hspace*{0.5em}\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\hspace*{0.5em} &
  \hspace*{0.5em}#3\hspace*{0.5em} \\
  \cline{1-1} \cline{2-2}
  \scriptsize Signature & \scriptsize Place, Date
  \end{tabular*}

  \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\declaratory[
  trim=0 20 0 0,
  width=5cm,
]{example-image}
{City, 31.02.2022}

\end{document}
```

In the picture the image is drawn behind the rule, in a real-world application the signature would be on a transparent background.

When your document is finished, you can go to the definition of `\declaratory` and fix the details.

Avoid things such as `\leavevmode\vfill`: LaTeX has `\vspace*{\fill}` for the purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With the help of a single `tabular*` environment: (Red lines indicate margins):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}wc{3cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}wc{3cm}@{}}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} &  Stade, 19.10.202 \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-2}
Signature &  Place, Date
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to move the text and image down by a few mm? I tried using ```\vspace``` but it did not work.

Comment: Which text? Do you want to move the image and the text above the horizontal line on the left closer to the horizontal line? Or something else?

Comment: The text above the horizontal line. And also the image.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative using 2 tabulars and `\hfill`.

I noticed a tendency for overkill, like using both `\noindent` and `Flushleft`.  One or the  other is sufficient.  Also, `\vspace` in hmode acts after the current line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\leavevmode\vfill

\begin{center}
    \textbf{DECLARATION}
\end{center}
``I hereby ensure the sole composure of the Master thesis without any other sources
than the ones mentioned or any other auxiliary means. All parts taken from other sources in verbatim or gist manner are indicated appropriately.''
\vspace{4em}

\noindent\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \includegraphics[height=2\normalbaselineskip]{example-image}\\[1ex]
    \hline
    \makebox[10em]{Signature}
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Stade, 19.10.2021\\[1ex]
    \hline
    \makebox[10em]{Place, Date}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```